# Regex to find Last name, first name or just first name

Tags: regex, actionscript-3

trying to write a regex that will extract a first and last name or just a first name depending on the format.

The two possible formats will be:

```
<Last name> / <first name>
```

Or:

```
<first name>
```

Is there a single regular expression that I can use to extract (with groups) the last name and first name if in the first format, or just the first name in the second format?

Thanks!
Kyle

Comment: Something like [`(?:<Last\s+(?<last>\S+)>\s*/\s*)?<first\s+(?<first>\S+)>`](https://regex101.com/r/rN5jP6/1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It needs to be said that the above RegEx from Mark will also match for: "1234hjkbj324     re23jh23ghjbpizza" or "Mark/342432bmnb"...

I don't recommend using this because you're going to receive some unexpected results. Also, I'm not convinced that the $1 variable won't capture the entire text line...so these capturing parentheses aren't wholly reliable either.

Try this RegEx; It's more specific and should give you more predictable results:

> ^([a-zA-z]+\s*/\s*)?([a-zA-Z]+)$

Works for: "Smith / Mark", "Mark / Smith", "Smith/Mark", "Mark/Smith", "Tony / Pizzeria", "Jimmy" ( it will also match "jimmy", "mark / smith" and other case-insensitive patterns; this is easily changeable )...you get the picture. Notice the whitespace on either side of the '/' is variable and the RegEx accounts for that. Remove the repetition operators (i.e. '*') that follow the '\s' if you don't want this behavior.
Note that this DOES NOT work for: "23432hjkjh      kjdhda8", "2134134 / Smith", "123412341/12341234", among others. This behavior is deliberate.

Also, if you want this to work for names that are embedded within a larger text file and not ones that appear on their own separate line, substitute '\b' for BOTH '^' and '$'. Or try substituting '\<' for '^' and '>' for '$'. This will work depending on which RegEx engine you're using and what that engine supports. These are PCREs though (Perl-Compatible Regular Expressions).

If any of this is unclear, or produces unexpected behavior, let me know. Good luck.

Comment: Depends how choosy you want to be on the format of names. Note that yours won't handle names with non a-z characters (e.g. Jóhn, John-Paul) :-)

Comment: You are correct about names with accents, but the solution to that problem is certainly not using the (dot) metacharacter. This particular case is not a matter of the level of "choosiness" in a RegEx; it's a matter of functionality versus non-functionality. Unless your RegEx was intended to parse Robot names ( e.g. PeterX425 / PlanetZargonX635 ), then its pattern matching is wrong and misleading. As for handling compound names, thank you for pointing this out to me. A fix is substituting "[-a-zA-Z]" for the already existent [a-zA-Z] character classes.

Comment: Depends upon the application I suppose but I'd rather have it work with accented names and allow robot names than vice versa. Jjjjjjooooooooohhhhhhhhhn is just as nonsensical as J0hn.

Answer (score 0):

```
^(?:(.*)\/)?(.*)$
```

will put the first name into $2, and the last name (if present) into $1.

Tested with:

```
Smith/Mark
Mark
```

If I've misinterpreted your notation, please say so.

Answer (score 0):

This regex pattern will look for the slash and capture everything before it as well as everything after it:

([^/]+)*/(.*)